# How to generate a new table row with an onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with 2 columns and 1 row. I would like it to generate another row with a clean set of inputs when users click the "add new row" button it.

Current HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea rows="5" cols="1" placeholder="Enter task description here..."></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><img src="" height="80"></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add new row">
```

How it currently looks:
[image]

I want the table add another table row when the user clicks the "Add new row" button.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy. You can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
function addNewRow() {
  let tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  tds[tds.length - 2].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<td><textarea rows="5" cols="1" placeholder="Enter task description here..."></textarea></td>')
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea rows="5" cols="1" placeholder="Enter task description here..."></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><img src="" height="80"></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add new row" onclick="addNewRow()">
```

With increasing placeholder:

```js
let i = 1;

function addNewRow() {
  i++;
  let tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  tds[tds.length - 2].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<td><textarea rows="5" cols="1" placeholder="Enter task description here #${i}"></textarea></td>`)
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea rows="5" cols="1" placeholder="Enter task description here #1"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><img src="" height="80"></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add new row" onclick="addNewRow()">
```

jQuery solution:

```js
function addNewRow() {
  $("td").eq($("td").length - 2).after('<td><textarea rows="5" cols="1" placeholder="Enter task description here..."></textarea></td>');
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea rows="5" cols="1" placeholder="Enter task description here..."></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><img src="" height="80"></td><br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add new row" onclick="addNewRow()">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would highly recommend you read up on `render` functions and implement here:
https://gomakethings.com/rendering-content-with-vanilla-javascript/